# Python self variables within a module

Tags: python

On executing this code, I expected 0 but instead got [10]. The question is how does self work and should it be used while declaring variables local to a function within the class. In mod_a and mod_b both x.self is suppose to be local. The list is the result of the return in Line 4 or self.variable is a global variable declaration?

I have read the python documentation which refers to "this" of c++ but I don't know c++, therefore decided to ask here. Incase its been answered before please point me to it, I don't think I am using the right keywords in my search.

```
 1  class ExampleClass(object):
 2    def mod_a(self):
 3      self.x=[10]
 4      return self.x
 5
 6    def mod_b(self):
 7      self.x=0
 8      self.mod_a()
 9      return self.x
10
11  if __name__=="__main__":
12    s=ExampleClass()
13    print s.mod_b()

Output 
 python test.py
[10]
```

Comment: self is not a part of Python.  It is a convention.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. It doesn't help solve my confusion.

Comment: You can write whatever you want as an argument to point to the current object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is the instance of the class that is currently being manipulated.  Note, there is nothing magical about the name `self` -- It is just a python variable like anything else.  Convention (strongly) dictates that the variable be named `self` however.  In other languages, it is sometimes called `this`, so if you really wanted to buck the trend, you could write a class like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(this):
        this.x = 12
```

Maybe to illuminate this a bit more, it would be worthwhile to print some Ids...

```
class Foo(object):
    def print_my_id(self):
        print(id(self))

    def print_my_id_delegator(self):
        self.print_my_id()

f = Foo()
print(id(f))
f.print_my_id()
f.print_my_id_delegator()
```

Now, if you look at the printout, you'll notice that all the numbers (id's) are the same.  So, when you write:

```
f.print_my_id()
```

python executes:

```
type(f).print_my_id(f)
```

which is the same as:

```
Foo.print_my_id(f)
```

Looking at it this way, you can see quite clearly what `self` is in this function call (it's `f`!)

Of course, we could reproduce this experiment with a different instance of `Foo` ...

```
g = Foo()
print(id(g))
g.print_my_id()
```

And now we see that python executed

```
Foo.print_my_id(g)
```

when you wrote that last line.

---

To bring this back to home with your code, in your case here, `mod_b` sets the `x` attribute on the instance to `0`, but then it calls `self.mod_a`.  The `self` in `mod_a` is the same self that was in `mod_b`, so it re-sets the value to `[10]`.

Comment: So within the scope of this class I am declaring a global variable by appending self to it, did I understand that correctly? Should I be using self to declare variables local to a function?

Comment: @Sameer -- I've updated my post.  Hopefully this makes it more clear?

Comment: @Sameer You got the first part right... sort of. It's _like_ a `global` var in that any variable prepended with `self.` is global to that instance's namespace and automatically becomes an attribute of that object. You can then change its value in one method and get it again using `self.`. If you want to declare variables local to a function, you don't prepend them with anything; by the time the function ends, the variable no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is a convention<sup>1</sup> used in python to mean "this object" or "the current object". It refers to the object that was used to call the function. While it may *look* like a local variable by virtue of being a parameter, it is not. It is a reference to the object itself. The variable `self` in `mod_a` is exactly the same as `self` in `mod_b` -- they both refer to the same object. Because of that, `self.x` in one method refers to the very same `self.x` in another method.

`self` is the thing that allows all of the methods within an object to refer to a common set of data. Not global per se, just visible only within the methods of the object.

<sup>1</sup> Note: `self` is just a convention. You can use any word you want. For example, the following code is completely acceptable according the rules of the language:

```
class ExampleClass(object):
  def mod_a(this_object):
    this_object.x=[10]
    return this_object.x

  def mod_b(this_object):
    this_object.x=0
    this_object.mod_a()
    return this_object.x
```

**However**, pretty much the whole python world uses `self`, so choosing some other word will make your code harder to understand.